# Unable to understand ftrace output

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to trace kernel using `ftrace`. I want to trace what are the functions called in kernel. I am able to capture the function trace from `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace`. But unable to understand. The most of the trace having below calls only. I am expecting function calls from application level to kernel level.

```
                                           get_page_from_freelist() {
 0)               |                          next_zones_zonelist() {
 0)   0.812 us    |                          } /* next_zones_zonelist */
 0)               |                          zone_watermark_ok() {
 0)               |                            __zone_watermark_ok() {
 0)   0.917 us    |                            } /* __zone_watermark_ok */
 0)   2.522 us    |                          } /* zone_watermark_ok */
 0)               |                          _raw_spin_lock_irqsave() {
 0)   0.825 us    |                          } /* _raw_spin_lock_irqsave */
 0)               |                          __rmqueue() {
 0)   0.963 us    |                          } /* __rmqueue */
 0)               |                          get_pageblock_flags_group() {
 0)   0.892 us    |                          } /* get_pageblock_flags_group */
 0)               |                          __mod_zone_page_state() {
 0)   0.833 us    |                          } /* __mod_zone_page_state */
 0) + 13.444 us   |                        } /* get_page_from_freelist */
 0) + 16.776 us   |                      } /* __alloc_pages_nodemask */
 0)               |                      mod_zone_page_state() {
 0)               |                        __mod_zone_page_state() {
 0)   0.900 us    |                        } /* __mod_zone_page_state */
 0)   2.476 us    |                      } /* mod_zone_page_state */
 0)               |                      kmem_cache_alloc() {
 0)   0.907 us    |                      } /* kmem_cache_alloc */
 0)               |                      __phys_addr() {
```

Comment: I used this guide in the past http://www.eballetbo.com/en/2012/12/seguint-un-proces-amb-ftrace/ to get me started

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the kernel program is similar to normal c: a main() program that call functions() and in functions call other sub-functions. For example:

```
void f1() {
     f2();
     f3();
}


void main() {
f1()
f4() 
}
```

The calling relations of a program will be a tree structure. In this example, the calling relation is

```
main() -> f1() -> f2()
               -> f3()
       -> f4()
```

the ftrace tools shows the kerne's calling functions and every function's spending time. In your ftrace result, it show kernel call get_page_from_freelist() first and spending 13us. Then kernel return from function __alloc_pages_nodemask. This function spends 16us, and so on.